# Getting empty list when loading from DB in a Hibernate's OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities: `Contrato` and `Historico` with following structure:

```
public class Contrato {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long contratoId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contrato", targetEntity = Historico.class,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Historico> historicos;
```

and

```
public class Historico {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long historicoId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="contratoId")
    private Contrato contrato;
```

But when I'm loading the `ContratoEntity` from database, I'm getting the correct object with an empty list of `Historico` objects. The loading of the object from the database :

```
private void preencheTabelaDePesquisa(List<Contrato> resultList) {
    DefaultTableModel model = pag1.getModelPage1(); 
    HashMap<Integer, Contrato> mapaLinha = pag1.getMapaLinha();
    limpaTabela(model);
    int i = 0;
    for (Contrato contrato : resultList) {
        List<Historico> historicoList = contrato.getHistoricos();
        for(Historico historico: historicoList){
            model.addRow(new Object[] { "", "", ""});
            model.setValueAt(contrato.getContrato(), i, 0);
            model.setValueAt(contrato.getNome(), i, 1);
            model.setValueAt(contrato.getStatus(), i, 2);
            model.setValueAt(historico.getDataVencimento(), i, 3);
            mapaLinha.put(i, contrato);
            i++;
        }
    }
    pag1.setMapaLinha(mapaLinha);
}
```

And the code's part where I save teh database:

```
public Map<String, Contrato> extraiDados() throws IOException {
    String path = "C:\\Users\\tathiana.i.oliveira\\Desktop\\contratos.xls";
    Map<String, Contrato> mapa = new HashMap<String, Contrato>();
    List<Historico> historicosList;
    Util u = new Util();
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
    HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    HSSFCell cell;
    HSSFRow row;
    int rowsCount = worksheet.getLastRowNum();
    Contrato contrato;
    Historico historico;
    String contratoKey;
    for (int i = 1; i <= rowsCount; i++) {
        try {
            row = worksheet.getRow(i);
            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("L"));
            contratoKey = u.devolveCampoLido(cell);

            if (mapa.containsKey(contratoKey)) {
                contrato = mapa.get(contratoKey);
                historicosList = contrato.getHistoricos();
            } else {
                contrato = new Contrato();
                historicosList = new ArrayList<Historico>();
            }

            contrato.setContrato(contratoKey);
            historico = new Historico();

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("A"));
            contrato.setClassificacao(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("B"));
            contrato.setResponsavel(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("C"));
            contrato.setUf(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("D"));
            contrato.setSigla(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("E"));
            contrato.setStatusContrato(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("F"));
            contrato.setFornecedor(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("G"));
            contrato.setSite(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("H"));
            contrato.setTelefone(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("I"));
            contrato.setCnpj(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("J"));
            contrato.setCodigoFornecedor(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("K"));
            contrato.setHidrometro(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("M"));
            contrato.setNome(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("N"));
            contrato.setEndereco(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("O"));
            contrato.setDespesa(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("P"));
            contrato.setDescricao(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("Q"));
            contrato.setMp(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("T"));
            contrato.setStatus(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("U"));
            contrato.setEstadoLancamento(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("R"));
            historico.setDataCobranca(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("S"));
            historico.setDataVencimento(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("V"));
            historico.setDataEmissao(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("Y"));
            historico.setDataLancamento(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("Z"));
            historico.setDataCompensacao(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("AA"));
            historico.setDataVencimento(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("AB"));
            historico.setDataAtualizacao(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("W"));
            historico.setDocPgt(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("X"));
            historico.setDocCompensacao(u.devolveCampoLido(cell));

            historicosList.add(historico);
            contrato.setHistoricos(historicosList);
            mapa.put(contrato.getContrato(), contrato);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            continue;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return mapa;
}
```

And the method when I actually save :

```
public void salva(Map<String,Contrato> contratoMap) {
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Contrato> entry : contratoMap.entrySet()) {
            Contrato contrato = entry.getValue();
            session.save(contrato);
            System.out.println("contrato salvo");
            List<Historico> historicoList = contrato.getHistoricos();
            for(Historico historico: historicoList){
                session.save(historico);
                System.out.println("historico salvo");
            }
        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

All the system.print it's working, so I guess I have been adding the Historico instances to the Contrato.historicos

[DEBUG'S LOOP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV7aJ.png)

Comment: Just to confirm, you have data in the database with the correct ID mappings?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint at the begining of your for loop, to check that the list actually is empty ?

Comment: Try calling em.refresh on the Contrato instance.  If it works, it means you haven't been adding the Historico instances to the Contrato.historicos.  The foreign key is updated when you modify the Historico.contrato relationship which causes many to forget that JPA allows caching and does not automatically set the other side of the relationship for you - the application must maintain both sides of bidirectional relationships or they can become inconsistent with what is in the database.

Comment: Hi Draken, thanks for your reply. I added more code on my question and I guess all my Contrato's intances have Historico.

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry for my knowledge leakage but I did not understand what em.refresh is. Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: Hi Jr593, I did it. In each loop, I have an object Contrato, with all yours parameters, but with a List<Historico> empty.

Comment: @Chris Just giving you a notification.

As for your response Tathiana, you guess isn't exactly concrete. Can you post a screenshot of your datasource showing a `Contrato` row having links to `Historico` rows?

Comment: Session.save isn't JPA - I'm guessing you are using native Hibernate API.  Refresh is a method on EntityManager, which is part of JPA.  the take away is that you need to check that you are setting both sides of your bidirectional relationships

Answer (score 0):

I was forgeting to set the other side of my bidirectional relationship, when I was reading the data from excel.

```
try {
        row = worksheet.getRow(i);
        cell = row.getCell(u.devolveNumColuna("L"));
        contratoKey = u.devolveCampoLido(cell);

        if (mapa.containsKey(contratoKey)) {
            contrato = mapa.get(contratoKey);
            historicosList = contrato.getHistoricos();
        } else {
            contrato = new Contrato();
            historicosList = new ArrayList<Historico>();
        }

        contrato.setContrato(contratoKey);
        historico = new Historico(); // here I need to set historico.setContrato(contrato)
```